Clipped raster is 5 times bigger than source
If I clip PROBAV (https://zenodo.org/records/3939050/files/PROBAV_LC100_global_v3.0.1_2019-nrt_Discrete-Classification-map_EPSG-4326.tif?download=1) worldwide raster with Deflate compression setting and Save resolution setting the result is  bigger than 6 gb. Although the source is 1.8 gb.
What other parameter(s) would make it smaller?
UPD:
I used parameters mentioned in the answer and I got 756 Mb raster for Eurasia. Solution found.

Compression would do that

I used Deflate compression (Predictor 2, ZLevel 9)

Check the data type of the clipped raster, in layer properties. The PROBAV uses 8-bit unsigned integer values. Probably the clipped layer uses 32-bit integers or floats, which will balloon the file size

Please edit your question to include the output of gdalinfo clipped_raster and also specify exactly how you clipped it.

I could not reproduce your issue. I made a test by clipping to the full extent of the source image. I adjusted couple of the parameters (predictor and zlevel) for making the conversion perhaps a bit faster. It took still over 15 minutes to run. I used tiled output because the source is tiled as well, and bigtiff I set just to be sure that the limit of TIFF will not be hit. This is the GDAL command that QGIS generated.
gdal_translate -projwin -180.0 80.0 180.0 -60.0 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=7 -co tiled=yes -co bigtiff=yes PROBAV_LC100_global_v3.0.1_2019-nrt_Discrete-Classification-map_EPSG-4326.tif clipped.tif

The size of "clipped.tif" is  1651388008 bytes, that is less than the original 1713345228 bytes.

Tiles are useful indeed. Thank you.
